как узнать 3 младших бита числа
Как узнать 3 младших (последних) бита 8-битного числа вида 1111 1111.
попытался сделать так, не понимаю что не получается.
unsigned char var;
unsigned char bmask <<= 7;

var = (var | bmask) >> 5;


Уточните, в каком виде вы их хотите "узнать", как 0/1, или как число, или как еще что-то?

Начнем с того, что unsigned char bmask <<= 7; не компилируется.

Так:  var &=  0x03;

3 бита  -  0x07..

@Kromster не важно, главное 1 2 4 биты

Биты считаются по номерам, 1,2,3, а не по степеням (1,2,4).

Биты принято нумеровать с нуля. Установить i-ый бит -- unsigned int bmask = 0, v = tested_value; bmask |= (1 << i); ; Проверить, что все биты из маски установлены -- ((v & bmask) == bmask); Проверить, что хотя бы один из битов маски установлен -- (v & bmask); Проверить, что все биты сброшены -- ((v & ~bmask) == 0);  Сделать маску из n установленных бит -- (1 << n) - 1;  Выделить (как число) поле бит длиной l, начинающееся с бита i -- (  (v >> i) & ((1 << l) - 1) ).  Запомните эти простые приемы и творчески их используйте
